# Получить значения другой таблицы и посчитать их

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

У меня есть таблица *storage* она содержит поле *fileid* и *userid*.
Другая таблица(откуда надо собирать и считать общее) называется *file* и содержит *size*.

Как составить запрос чтобы я получил общее число всех *file.size(и только)* используя `storage.userid = 1`?

Если это важно, то база данных у меня *sqlite*, но может быть и *mysql* т.е. без привязки к определенной БД

**Обновление**

Возникла проблема именно "как", я не имею представления, что именно делать. Использовать join? Не выполняет нужную мне функцию

```
$this->modelsManager->createBuilder() ->from('Models\Storage')->where('Models\Storage.userid = 1')->join('Models\File', 'Models\File.id = Models\Storage.fileid')->columns('sum(size)')->getQuery()->execute()->toarray();
```

Результат вышел таков.

Comment: это не место вопросам "как" покажите что Вы хоть что-то попытались сделать сами(код) и и в чем у Вас возникла ошибка или проблема.

Comment: изучайте [sql](http://www.sql.ru/). нам необходимо видеть, что Вы хоть что-то пробуете делать(Ваш код)

Comment: Что именно у Вас не получилось с `join` или Вы уже разобрались?

Comment: Обязательно изучайте и функции и синтаксис - интересная вещь. Для того, чтобы получить нужный ответ можно пойти разными путями. Можно было бы, например, сделать [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd0a7/2). Хотя движок БД скорее всего привел бы это к варианту с `join` внутри себя.

Comment: Какой из этих вариантов менее нагрузит БД при записях более 10k в таблице file?

ORM позволяет использовать как свои SQL(целиком), составлять(что я и сделал) или сгенерировать его. Следовательно, это уже каким путем пойду я для выполнения запроса. "Движок" запрос бы не изменил, а выдал бы ошибку если не получатся сгенерировать чистый SQL. К слову, использую я Phalcon ORM.

Comment: Я имел ввиду движок самой базы данных - который как-то перерабатывает текстовый запрос, строит план запроса, а потом выполняет его. Я думаю Вам проще оставить тот вариант, что в ответе - он должен быть оптимальнее. Тем более 10к записей должно быть достаточно мало для базы данных в любом случае. Самое главное - оптимизировать что-то стоит только тогда, когда проблема реально появилась и никак не раньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить то, что Вы хотите - Вам нужно сначала виртуально соединить таблицы `file` и `storage` используя конструкцию [join](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), а затем выполнить функцию `sum` на нужной Вам колонке:

```
select sum(size) total_size
from storage s
  join file f on f.fileid = s.fileid
where s.userid = 1
```

[Sql fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd0a7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Получаем сумму size:

```
SELECT SUM(size) FROM storage WHERE userid = '1'
```

Для двух таблиц с использованием left join:

```
SELECT SUM(size) FROM storage as st
  left join file as f on f.fileid = st.fileid
where st.userid = 1
```

P.S.: или просто через join

Comment: Я указал, что у меня 2 таблицы, но вы мне уже подсказали решение. Спасибо.

Comment: обновили ответ.